# Mask the field that returns number

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I need to apply a mask both to the Input (which has '.' and',' by default), and to the return (which is inside a tag 'p'). I didn't intend to use jQuery, so I would need another solution, I did some research on some libraries, but I didn't succeed.

Input:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Valor Estimado</label>
   <input [(ngModel)]="ticket.valorestimado" type="number" class="form-control" id="value"
    aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Valor"/>
</div>
```

Return value:

```
<div>
   <p class="fz-13">R$ {{ j.valorestimado }}</p>
</div
```

Comment: Can you give some example inputs and outputs

Comment: Input: 3000000
Output: 30.000,00

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format the number 30000 as '30,000.00', you can use the number pipe.

```
<div>
   <p class="fz-13">R$ {{ j.valorestimado | number:'1.2-2' }}</p>
</div>
```

Edit:

This will use the default locale of your app. See the number pipe documentation for more details: https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe.

I chose the format `1.2-2` for at least 1 integer, and between 2 and 2 (i.e. exactly 2) fraction digits.

From the docs:

> Decimal representation options, specified by a string in the following format:
>
> {minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}

Comment: In the output, it worked, the 30.000,00 returned, but in the input, it is also necessary to format the field '99.999,99 '

Comment: As long as it's a pure number coming in, it should just work. Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2euwu7